# Redux dispatch not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux

The code runs when it is on the same file but i came across on error when i try to separate the concern as shown below, my intention is to send the props down to the presentational component and when the presentation component passes the callback method so that the container automatically invoke mapdispatchtoprops.

This the container component

```
    class BankAppContainer extends Component{

          render(){

            let {onDeposit, onWithdraw, balance} = this.props
            return(
              <BankApp
                balance = {balance}
                onDeposit={(amount)=>this.props.onWithdraw(amount)}
                onWithdraw={(amount)=>this.props.onWithdraw(amount)}
                />
            )
          }
        }

        const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
          return {
              balance: state.balance }
        }

        const mapDispatchToProps = (dispath) => {

                return {
                onDeposit: (amount) => dispatch(bankActionCreators.depositIntoAccount(amount)),
                onWithdraw: (amount) => dispatch(bankActionCreators.withdrawFromAccount(amount)) }
                }

                export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BankAppContainer)
```

And this pure component

```
class BankApp extends Component {



  handleDeposit() {
    if(this.refs.amount.value!=''){
      this.props.onDeposit(this.refs.amount.value);
      this.refs.amount.value = '';
    }
    else{
      console.log("Enter a value")
    }

  }
  handleWithdraw() {
    if(this.refs.amount.value!=''){
      this.props.onWithdraw(this.refs.amount.value);
      this.refs.amount.value = '';
    }
    else{
      console.log("Enter a value")
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Your balance is ${(this.props.balance)}</h1>
          <div className="atm">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Ammount" ref="amount" />
            <button onClick={this.handleWithdraw.bind(this)}>Withdraw</button>
            <button onClick={this.handleDeposit.bind(this)}>Deposit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

And got Uncaught ReferenceError: dispatch is not defined.
how shall i fix ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo, it should be `dispatch` not `dispath`